# Using fio to continuously send IO to the NFS share and got the "Input/output error" occasionally

Tags: nfs

The script I'm using is below:

```
for n in {1..70}; do
    fio --name=randrw$( printf %09d "$n" ) --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=128 --rw=randrw --bs=128k --direct=1 --size=50M --numjobs=300 --runtime=2400 --time_based --group_reporting >> ./fio.log
done
```

And the error is like below and it happened almost a hundred times to different files or the same file multiple times. I googled similar issues, but most of them just happened right after they ran the fio command, but not my case. My error happened in the middle of some time.

```
fio: io_u error on file randrw000000042.234.0: Input/output error
     write offset=41549824, buflen=131072
fio: io_u error on file randrw000000042.108.0: Input/output error
     write offset=11927552, buflen=131072
fio: io_u error on file randrw000000042.108.0: Input/output error
     write offset=34865152, buflen=131072
```

I talked with the NFS server side and they found that the server was busy that time and the write didn't success, so the server returned "write size = 0". Seems like fio didn't handle this return or it's actually a NFS server bug?

BTW, the fio version is fio-2.1.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this one was [asked over on fio's github issue tracker](https://github.com/axboe/fio/issues/551) (I'd have said the mailing list would have been the better place to have asked though) and the evidence points to the NFS server being so overloaded by I/O that it decided to tell the client that it didn't try and complete some of the I/Os.